# Javascript em popup não enxerga os campos da página pai

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Tenho uma consulta em uma popup que o resultado é retornado em uma gridview. Na gridview eu tenho um botão onde eu chamo uma função javascript que insere o resultado correlacionando o retorno da consulta com os campos da página principal. Estou conseguindo entrar na função, mas quando eu chego na parte que faz o relacionamento, surge o erro:

> window.opener.document.frm is undefined

O trecho:

```
 window.opener.document.frm.txtDS_PES.value = trim(pesnm);
```

No firebug eu indentifiquei que a partir do frm.txtDES_PES.value ele da undefined.

```
<form id="frm" runat="server">
```

Comment: Tente verificar se você pode acessar o opener com var opener = window.opener;
if(opener) {//Teste}

Comment: Não é o caso. Pois consigo acessar a outra página, só não os objetos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cria uma função na sua página normal (sem ser a popup) pra atualizar os valores de acordo com o **ids**.

```
function atualizaValor(id, value)
{
    document.getElementById(id).value = value;
}
```

E depois na sua *popup* é só chamar:

```
window.opener.atualizaValor('txtDS_PES', trim(pesnm));
```

Comment: tenho uns 20 campos para fazer essa atualização. Não vai ficar pesado?

Comment: Acredito que não, afinal são 20 `tags` diferentes né?

Comment: Da o erro: TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null, engraçado é que ele reconhece a outra página e ainda reconhece a função.

Comment: como tu sabe que reconhece a outra página?

Comment: Porque eu tô fazendo o Debug do fire bug! Inclusive eu coloquei um break point na pagina principal e ele entra no atualizarValor.

Comment: então o problema está nas suas tags, você tem algum input com o **ID** txtDS_PES?

Comment: ou esse txtDS_PES é o name?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25248/discussion-between-maicon-carraro-and-germano-sampaio).

Comment: o problema é que além de está passando o valor para um textbox visible=false, eu estava passando o nome do ID corretamente. Pois quando o site é renderizado, os componentes mudam de nome. A solução foi passar o ContentPlaceHolder1_ na frente do campo. Exemplo: ContentPlaceHolder1_txtDS_PES e na página, ao invés de passar um campo visible=false, eu utilizei o componente asp:HiddenField. Agora o problema é que quando eu fecho a popup os dados da que foram para tela principal desaparece.

Comment: Quando tu fecha a `popup` não está fazendo algum postback pra tela anterior, não?

Comment: Atualiza as tags <span> mas quando dou um window.close() na popup as informações na tela pai n permanecem. Eu não quero que a tela pai dê o refresh, pois tenho mais dois acessos a popup a fazer antes de jogar no banco. Eu não quero ter que ir ao servidor para fazer isso!

Comment: Tenta utilizar `UpdatePanel` pra não forçar a atualização, se quiser podemos ir chat

Comment: Deu certo com o UpdatePanel . Obrigado!